# mercury planet etymology

Tags: astrology

what is significance for mercury planet getting named ***budha*** in the vedic astrological paradigm?

the samaveda addendum, [Pancavimsa Brahmana](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.203661/2015.203661.Pancavimsa-Brahmana_djvu.txt), is most likely extant origin for the vestige budha, but is this a reference to mercury planet, or a formless god, or a plant (soma)? from what i understand, planets for whatever reason are associated with gods like rama, krsna, etc.  is mercury (budha) associated with shakyamuni buddha?

> One of the earliest mentions of Budha as a celestial body appears in
> the Vedic text [Pancavimsa Brahmana](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.203661/2015.203661.Pancavimsa-Brahmana_djvu.txt), and it appears in other ancient
> texts such as the Shatapatha Brahmana as well, but not in the context
> of astrology. In the ancient texts, Budha is linked to three steps of
> the Hindu god Vishnu

who is the white prince in this [**art**](https://indianculture.gov.in/museums/vishnu-dwarf-asking-three-steps-land)?

Comment: The *graha*'s name is *Budha*  while the person's name which you are referring to is *Buddha*, they aren't similar at all . Mercury is an english name derived from the Latin *mercurius*. On the other hand, *Budha* is a Sanskrit name.  The name *Buddha* is derived from *bodhi* whose verbal root is *budh* i.e. (to wake up, to be awake, to be awakened). It has little relation to the planetary deity *Budha*, and *Buddha* isn't named after it. And no one confuses *Buddha* with the planet *Budha*, they are not same terms.

Comment: In mythology  and Indian astronomical texts,  Mercury is identified with *Budha*, patron of merchants and son of Chandra (the Moon) and either Rohiṇi (Aldebaran) or Tārā (wife of Jupiter). In later Purāṇic literature it is also known as  Saumya, Rauhiṇeya and Tuṅga , the first extant explicit mention of Budha (Budh in Hindi) as the planet Mercury occurs in the Pañcaviṃśa Brāhmaṇa (after 1900 B.C.). In the Ṛgveda and Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa, the term Budha is also used, but not for a planet. In Āryabhaṭīya and later texts *Budha* is used for Mercury

Comment: For some of the above info related to *Budha*, its mentioned here https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-7951-2_1

Comment: I already told you the naming and the origins , if you want to still assert that the planet's name Budha is derived from Buddha, please argue that based on proper source because your sense of etymology of the two terms is lacking, as in the question. We don't want airy arguments which are governed by intuition rather than facts. The name *budha* is already mentioned in the Vedas, which are pre-Buddha texts.

Comment: Pañcaviṃśa Brāhmaṇa( 24.18) of Sāma Veda speaks of Budha in connection with a 61 day rite. Three such rites imply a total of 183 days which equals the days exclusively devoted to the heavens. This appears to be the analog, in the field of ritual, of the three steps of Viṣṇu covering the heavens in R̥g Veda 1.154.1. Kak interprets  the three steps of Viṣṇu as three successive revolutions of Mercury in 261 sidereal days (sideral period 87 days).
R̥g Veda 10.101.1 uses term  *budhyadhvaṃ* derived from root *budh* meaning (to awake, awaken), which I already mentioned before.

Comment: You can check Kak's paper here  https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0101063
And have a good day/night, and please be respectful if you want answers.

Comment: Yes @Bingming u r genius! Good a+ fantastic journey home mind blowing spectacular!

Comment: apparently, I have already given my points along with references. And also, I don't rely on wiki. Both the sources I used were scholarly. And the rest are primary sources. Believe what you want, that's not my matter. But when you argue your point, argue with facts hers.

Comment: @Bingming i revert my dismissal of your earlier comments, and apologies

Comment: @blue_ego i think it's indra, but i'm not sure

Comment: It's alright, it's been a long time. If you find a better answer, you can add it yourself. I have nothing more to say.